# Get Class Not Found Exception Java in From Cloud SDK Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, java-8, google-cloud-sdk

The error occurs when I type 'gradle appengineRun'. The command hangs at 85%. When I visit localhost:8080 it returns Error 503. The following is the output of the command:

```
        ~/Code/gradle-google-cloud-engine-hello$ gradle appengineRun:compileJava NO-SOURCE
            :processResources NO-SOURCE
            :classes UP-TO-DATE
            :war UP-TO-DATE
            :explodeWar UP-TO-DATE
            :assemble UP-TO-DATE
            :appengineRun
            2017-11-26 23:44:15.912:INFO::main: Logging initialized @303ms
            2017-11-26 23:44:16.202:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
            2017-11-26 23:44:16.303:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=0ms
            2017-11-26 23:44:16.446:WARN:oejs.BaseHolder:main: 
            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysite.server.ComingSoonServlet
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:196)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:95)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:363)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:891)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
                lyArgs(Parser.java:47)
                    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
                    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
            Nov 27, 2017 4:44:16 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
            SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
            javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Class loading error for holder comingsoon@70f7c77c==mysite.server.ComingSoonServlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false
'''skip'''com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
            2017-11-26 23:44:16.542:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@32ee6fee{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
            2017-11-26 23:44:16.543:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @935ms
            Nov 27, 2017 4:44:16 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
            INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
            Nov 27, 2017 4:44:16 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
            INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
            Nov 26, 2017 11:44:16 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
            INFO: Dev App Server is now running
            > Building 85% > :appengineRun
```